# How to use a different value from the record with SelectInput in react admin 3?

Tags: javascript, react-admin

Within react-admin, I want to select from a `record` a value which is not the `id`.

```
<ReferenceInput
  source="stripeProductId"
  reference={'products'}
  perPage={1000}
  allowEmpty={false}
>
  <SelectInput
    source="stripeProductId"
    optionText="name"
  />
</ReferenceInput>
```

This is my `product`:

```
{
  "id": 10,
  "stripeProductId": "pr_4fo12412"
}
```

This is what I expect to create in my `record.stripeProductId`:

```
{
  "id": 15,
  "stripeProductId": "pr_4fo12412"
}
```

This is what I get instead:

```
{
  "id": 15,
  "stripeProductId": "10
}
```

How can I use a `record` in React Admin v3, to copy a field value in another entity?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't the `optionValue` prop on the SelectInput help?

Docs: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#common-input-props, the SelectInput section

> You can customize the properties to use for the option name and value,
>   thanks to the optionText and optionValue attributes

Comment: I already tried but the problem is that it does perform a different reference request using the `optionValue`, while I only want to save a different value.